# Using gooddata-js SDK outside without node.js

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, gooddata

Looking at the code on this I can see that calls to methods like user.login() don't include the domain and so only appear to work when running via the grunt dev task.

Apologies if this is a noob question but how can we put this into production? We simply need to call user.isLoggedIn() and user.logout() from a script on our site but I can't see how we do that with the dist file.

Answer (score 2):

<s>Right now we don't support CORS so it is only possible using some kind of server side proxy on your side.</s>

We support CORS now on white-labeled domains so if this is your case you can embed your code to your GoodData dashboard (see [Embedding Viz tutorial](http://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-js/tutorial/embedding-custom-visualization-into-dashboard/)).

The only modification to you code would be calling `gooddata.config.setCustomDomain` (see [API docs](http://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-js/api/classes/config.html)) function before any actual call to the api (like `login`).

You can start with modifying our own proxy used in grunt dev task - see `request_proxy.js` and `cookie_domain_stripper.js` from https://github.com/gooddata/grunt-grizzly/tree/master/lib/middleware

Comment: Thanks @akloboucnik. I'm not clear on how we would include edited versions of those files as we're not using a modular approach. This is a very simple site with an embedded iframe and we just have a copy of jQuery and a single script file for the site's functionality. Would we just include a copy of each of those along with the JS SDK file?

Comment: Sorry - I didn't make it clear enough. What I meant was that you need to use this proxy on your backend (server - which serves the actual html page which you then embed). You probably have some kind of backend and you need to make it so that if your script on html page asks for url matching pattern `/gdc/*` (which gooddata-js does) it will be proxied from your server to `secure.gooddata.com` (our API endpoint) - which in case of node.js backend can be achieved by `request_proxy.js` middleware from the link above.

Comment: Ah right, this has probably passed my level of understanding at this point. We've plugged in a proxy script and using a sample login call, are seeing a Java exception which looks like it's down to how the URL is called or passed along: "message" : "Invalid uri 'http://na1-www01:666/gdc/account/login?{%22postUserLogin%22:{%22login%22:%22USER%22,%22password%22:%22PASSWORD%22,%22remember%22:1,%22captcha%22:%22%22,%22verifyCaptcha%22:%22%22}}': Invalid query".

Are you able to provide us with some support to get this to work?